# Changing the background property of the html, not the body

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

How do I change the background property of the html? I was able to change the background of the body element, but I want to manipulate the html "tag" (?).

**Code to manipulate the body background**

```
document.body.style = 'background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(131,170,203,1) 4%, rgba(69,113,148,1) 50%, rgba(39,71,97,1) 100%);';
```

**These attempts didn't work**

```
document.html.style = 'background: red';
document.style = 'background: red';
```

**I want to change this part**

```
html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;

    background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(131,170,203,1) 4%, rgba(69,113,148,1) 50%, rgba(39,71,97,1) 100%);
}
```

Comment: why try to check the html document when the visible part is the body element? What is wrong with using the correct element?

Comment: My body height is changing, when the user expands a table or similar and this causes some ugly effects, because the background re-adjusts. With the background property inside the html this isn't happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `document.documentElement.style` to target the `html` element.

```js
document.body.style = 'background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(131,170,203,1) 4%, rgba(69,113,148,1) 50%, rgba(39,71,97,1) 100%);';

document.documentElement.style = 'background: red';
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>test</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

change background by javascript in html tag
try this :

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.background="radial-gradient(circle, rgba(131,170,203,1) 4%, rgba(69,113,148,1) 50%, rgba(39,71,97,1) 100%)";
```

Answer (score -1):

just put a background-div in the DOM and manipulate it.
e.G. position: absolute / z-index: -1